# Can we use angular-cli for production

Tags: angular-cli

I am trying angular seed for product development but the issues is i am not able to integrate some library in that.
So, then i switched to angular command line for product development.
I just want to know that command line version of angular is good for production or not.

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse you can use command line version of angular for production,

If you create application using Angular CLI it does not difference while in production, it is just a command line tool for creating angular apps. It is recommended to use angular cli for creating angular apps as you don't need to spend time installing and configuring all the required dependencies and wiring everything together. Basically, angular-cli provides you with boilerplates and therefore, saves your time. Nothing else